# create a responsive menu and submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a responsive menu but there is a problem. It works perfectly in a desktop browser but when touched in a mobile browser there is a problem when I expand the menu's sub-menu. After I move down and up, the menu often gets hidden.

```
<style>
*{margin:0;padding:0;text-decoration:none}
body{background:#555;}
header{position:relative;width:100%;background:#333;}
.logo{position:relative;z-index:123;padding:10px;font:18px verdana;color:#6DDB07;float:left;width:15%}
.logo a{color:#6DDB07;}
nav{position:relative;width:980px;margin:0 auto;}
#cssmenu,#cssmenu ul,#cssmenu ul li,#cssmenu ul li a,#cssmenu #head-mobile{border:0;list-style:none;line-height:1;display:block;position:relative;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
#cssmenu:after,#cssmenu > ul:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;visibility:hidden;line-height:0;height:0}
#cssmenu #head-mobile{display:none}
#cssmenu{font-family:sans-serif;background:#333}
#cssmenu > ul > li{float:left}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{padding:17px;font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;text-decoration:none;color:#ddd;font-weight:700;}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul li.active a{color:#fff}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover,#cssmenu ul li.active:hover,#cssmenu ul li.active,#cssmenu ul li.has-sub.active:hover{background:rgba(18, 118, 142, 0.71) !important;-webkit-transition:background .3s ease;-ms-transition:background .3s ease;transition:background .3s ease;}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a{padding-right:30px}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:11px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{position:absolute;top:19px;right:14px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#ddd;content:'';-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;transition:all .25s ease}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:23px;height:0}
#cssmenu ul ul{position:absolute;left:-9999px}
#cssmenu ul ul li{height:0;-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;background:#333;transition:all .25s ease}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover{}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul{left:auto}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li{height:35px}
#cssmenu ul ul ul{margin-left:100%;top:0}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.15);padding:11px 15px;width:170px;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;color:#ddd;font-weight:400;}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a{border-bottom:0}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover{color:#fff}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after{position:absolute;top:16px;right:11px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before{position:absolute;top:13px;right:14px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#ddd;content:'';-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;transition:all .25s ease}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:17px;height:0}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover,#cssmenu ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover{background:#363636;}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a{border-left:1px solid #333}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,#cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active> a{border-top:1px solid #333}

@media screen and (max-width:700px){

#cssmenu,#cssmenu ul,#cssmenu ul li,#cssmenu ul li a,#cssmenu #head-mobile{border:0;list-style:none;line-height:1;display:block;position:relative;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
.logo{position:absolute;top:0;left: 0;width:100%;height:46px;text-align:center;padding:10px 0 0 0 ;float:none}
.logo2{display:none}
nav{width:100%;}
#cssmenu{width:100%}
#cssmenu ul{width:100%;display:none}
#cssmenu ul li{width:100%;border-top:1px solid #444}
#cssmenu ul li:hover{background:#363636;}
#cssmenu ul ul li,#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li{height:auto}
#cssmenu ul li a,#cssmenu ul ul li a{width:100%;border-bottom:0}
#cssmenu > ul > li{float:none}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{padding-left:25px}
#cssmenu ul ul li{background:#333!important;}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover{background:#363636!important}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a{padding-left:35px}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{color:#ddd;background:none}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a{color:#fff}
#cssmenu ul ul,#cssmenu ul ul ul{position:relative;left:0;width:100%;margin:0;text-align:left}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before{display:none}
#cssmenu #head-mobile{display:block;padding:23px;color:#ddd;font-size:12px;font-weight:700}
.button{width:55px;height:46px;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;cursor:pointer;z-index: 12399994;}
.button:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:20px;display:block;height:4px;width:20px;border-top:2px solid #dddddd;border-bottom:2px solid #dddddd;content:''}
.button:before{-webkit-transition:all .3s ease;-ms-transition:all .3s ease;transition:all .3s ease;position:absolute;top:16px;right:20px;display:block;height:2px;width:20px;background:#ddd;content:''}
.button.menu-opened:after{-webkit-transition:all .3s ease;-ms-transition:all .3s ease;transition:all .3s ease;top:23px;border:0;height:2px;width:19px;background:#fff;-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);-o-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg)}
.button.menu-opened:before{top:23px;background:#fff;width:19px;-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);-o-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg)}
#cssmenu .submenu-button{position:absolute;z-index:99;right:0;top:0;display:block;border-left:1px solid #444;height:46px;width:46px;cursor:pointer}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened{background:#262626}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button{height:34px;width:34px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:19px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after{top:15px;right:13px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after{background:#fff}
#cssmenu .submenu-button:before{position:absolute;top:19px;right:22px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before{top:12px;right:16px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before{display:none}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a{border-left:none}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,#cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a{border-top:none}
}
</style>
<script src="js/jquery2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
$.fn.menumaker = function(options) {  
 var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
   format: "dropdown",
   sticky: false
 }, options);
 return this.each(function() {
   $(this).find(".button").on('click', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
     var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
     if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
       mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
     }
     else {
       mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
       if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
         mainmenu.find('ul').show();
       }
     }
   });
   cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
multiTg = function() {
     cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
     cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
       if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
         $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
       }
       else {
         $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
       }
     });
   };
   if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
   else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
   if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
resizeFix = function() {
  var mediasize = 700;
     if ($( window ).width() > mediasize) {
       cssmenu.find('ul').show();
     }
     if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
       cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
     }
   };
   resizeFix();
   return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
 });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
   format: "multitoggle"
});
});
})(jQuery);

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<header>
<nav id='cssmenu'>

<div id="head-mobile"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='Home'>HOME</a></li>
<li><a href='Business_Unit_?Business_Unit_id=0'>Business Unit</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href='Business_Unit_?Business_Unit_id=1'>GALAXY BANGLADESH</a></li>
      <li><a href='Business_Unit_?Business_Unit_id=2'>AIRLINES GSA</a></li>
      <li><a href='Business_Unit_?Business_Unit_id=3'>LOGISTIC & FORWARDING</a></li>
      <li><a href='Business_Unit_?Business_Unit_id=4'>TRAVEL/TOUR</a></li>
      <li><a href='Business_Unit_?Business_Unit_id=5'>SHIPPING & NVOCC</a></li>
      <li><a href='Business_Unit_?Business_Unit_id=6'>EXPRESS</a></li>
      <li><a href='Business_Unit_?Business_Unit_id=7'>Facilitation Service</a></li>
      <li><a href='Business_Unit_?Business_Unit_id=8'>WARE HOUSE</a></li>
      <li><a href='Business_Unit_?Business_Unit_id=9'>HOSPITALITY</a></li>
      <li><a href='Business_Unit_?Business_Unit_id=10'>VSL OPERATION</a></li>
      <li><a href='Business_Unit_?Business_Unit_id=11'>HEALTH CARE/MEDICAL TOURISM</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='facts?id=facts'>FACTS</a>
          <ul>
                <li><a href="facts?id=AIR_GALAXY">Air Galaxy</a></li>
                <li><a href="facts?id=SHIPPING">Shipping</a></li>
                <li><a href="facts?id=HEALTH">Health Care </a></li>
                <li><a href="facts?id=LOGISTIC">Logistic</a></li>


          </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='our_team.php?content=Management_Body'>OUR TEAM</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="our_team.php?content=Management_Body">Management Body</a></li>
            <li><a href="our_team.php?content=Professionals">Professionals</a></li>
            <li><a href="our_team.php?content=Group_photo_Photo_gallery">Group photo/Photo gallery</a></li>


            </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='EXPLORE_US?id=who_are_we'>EXPLORE US</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="EXPLORE_US?id=who_are_we">who are we</a></li>
               <!-- <li><a href="component/content/73">Health and Safety</a></li> --->
                <li><a href="EXPLORE_US?id=Our_strength">Our strength</a></li>



                </ul>

</li>
<li><a href='contact'>Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather look at Bootstrap Navigation menu. That should help you create a navigation menu without much pain. [Check out the w3schools tuts](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

Once you have done the same. Just redesign it.

Comment: i don't want to use bootstrap

Comment: Dont use slide toggle. Use a variable like $menu_1_open or something and slide down or up when touched based on the value of this variable. And use jquery mobile plugin and .tap() event

Comment: can you tell me or suggest me any website for know about it

Comment: many website has a responsive menu but now i know that togle make problem then what can i use for expand manu